# PHP - Issue with connecting to Exchange Web Service

Tags: php, class, variables, soap, exchangewebservices

I´m just getting familiar with using Exchange Web Service (EWS) and the guidelines provided on the web (for example [Talking SOAP with Exchange](http://www.howtoforge.com/talking-soap-with-exchange)).

I have a test server where I´m getting the correct response. When I moved the `exact same files` to the production server I get no response (blank page) with the following PHP Notice:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in index.php on line 48
```

index.php Lines 44 to 48:

```
    44 - $FindFolder->Traversal = 'Shallow';
    45 - $FindFolder->FolderShape->BaseShape = 'AllProperties';
    46 - $FindFolder->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Id = 'root';
    47 - $result = $client->FindFolder($FindFolder);
    48 - $folders = $result->ResponseMessages->FindFolderResponseMessage->RootFolder->Folders->Folder;
```

A `var_dump($client)` after line 47 returns the correct data. But then after turning the Class object to a variable in `line 47: $result = $client->...` a `var_dump($result)` returns `NULL` (on the production server but is full of data in the test server).

I know that PHP classes are case sensitive but the case seems correct to me and this works on the test server.

**Any ideas?**

**Update # 1**

I added more details about the var_dumps for tracing the issue. These dumps are ALL placed after line 47:

var_dump($FindFolder)

```
object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["Traversal"]=> string(7) "Shallow" ["FolderShape"]=>
object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["BaseShape"]=> string(13) "AllProperties" } ["ParentFolderIds"]=>
object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["DistinguishedFolderId"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["Id"]=> 
string(4) "root" } } }
```

var_dump($client)

```
object(ExchangeNTLMSoapClient)#1 (5) { ["user":protected]=> string(6) "***hidden***"
["password":protected]=> string(8) "***hidden***" ["_soap_version"]=> int(1) ["sdl"]=>
resource(3) of type (Unknown) ["__last_request_headers"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(12)
"Method: POST" [1]=> string(22) "Connection: Keep-Alive" [2]=> string(25) "User-Agent:
PHP-SOAP-CURL" [3]=> string(37) "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" [4]=> string(85)
"SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/FindFolder"" } }
```

var_dump($result)

```
NULL
```

**Update # 2**
Just to be sure, I tested cURL on the production server and it works. I also notices a slight difference in the var_dump from the test server and the production server:

Relevant part of the var_dump($client) from test server:

```
["user:protected"]
```

Relevant part of the var_dump($client) from production server:

```
["user":protected]
```

The quotes are not on the same place. Is that relevant and causing the query not to connect and thus not data being returned? If so, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally I think I have traced this to a bug in PHP 5.3.3 or in the Talking SOAP with Exchange with PHP 5.3.3

My best guess is that there is a bug in how the protected variable is phrased as mentioned in update 2 in the original post.

Relevant `var_dump($client)` from servers running PHP 5.1.1 and another 5.2.17:

```
["user:protected"]
```

Relevant `var_dump($client)` from server running PHP 5.3.3:

```
["user":protected]
```

So I´m going to have to change to a hosting provider with an older version of PHP i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Does FindFolder returns a object (ex. return $this) ?

Method-chaining requires an object to be returned.

http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1163-php5-method-chaining.html

Comment: I added a more detailed traces of the var_dump in the original post. Please let me know if this does not fully answer your question. I´ll do whatever I can to answer your reply, but I´m still a beginner :)